# Integration of Exponential and Logarithms, $\int_{z-1}^z \log(\frac{1}{z-y}) \exp (-| y| ^{3}) \, dy$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, logarithms, exponential-function

The integral I am dealing with is:

$$\frac{3}{2 \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)}\int_{z-1}^z \log \left(\frac{1}{z-y}\right) \exp \left(-\left| y\right| ^{3}\right) \, dy$$

where $z\in \mathbb{R}$

Due to its complexity, I tried Mathematica to solve the integral. It gave back the same form. Does that mean it cant be solve? Or are there any other methods to solve such complex integrals? A handbook?

Comment: I would start with $y \mapsto y-z+1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $z\geq 1$, we have:
$$ \int_{z-1}^{z}\log\left(\frac{1}{z-y}\right) e^{-y^3}\,dy = -\frac{d}{d\alpha}\left.\int_{z-1}^{z}(z-y)^{\alpha}e^{-y^3}\,dy\,\right|_{\alpha=0} $$
hence the original integral depends on the derivatives of incomplete gamma functions.